# balancing reluctant and greedy matching

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

I am trying to match the two address lines below (mostly fictional addresses):

```
2320 ZINER CIR East 43123
1111 ZINER CIR East Bernstadt 43123
```

My regular expression is built using names of cities, and East Bernstadt is a city name. However, streets can also end in "East". My predicament then is that if I greedy match "East", as in:

```
\d+ [^ ]+ CIR( East)?( East Bernstadt)?(?: \d+)?
```

...then only the fist line is matched (the other is a partial match). If I use a reluctant match, as in:

```
\d+ [^ ]+ CIR( East)??( East Bernstadt)?(?: \d+)?
```

...the second line matches but not the first.

How can I change the regular expression so that both lines are matched completely? "East" and "East Bernstadt" must remain in separate parts of the expression.

*EDIT:* I cannot treat "East" and "East Bernstadt" with one parenthesis group; both expressions above must match, but also "1234 Ziner CIR East East Bernstadt" must match as well (some streets have cardinal directions on them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
\d+\s+\S+\s+CIR(?:(?!\sEast Bernstadt)\s+East)?(?:\s+East Bernstadt)?(?: +\d+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT8bL1/1)

**Explanation:**
`\s`: "whitespace character": space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab [sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD4dR7/1)
`\S`: One character that is not a whitespace character as defined by `\S` [sample](https://regex101.com/r/nT7lB4/1)
`(?!…)`: Negative lookahead [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bI9fA5/1)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't put East and East Bernstadt in the same expression because they are completely different units. For example, this will not match "1234 Ziner CIR East East Bernstadt". Some streets have a cardinal direction on the end. I'll edit the question to add this.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you.